# Button reply comment on Blogger doesn't works

Tags: comments, blogger, reply

Please help me, why my button reply in my blog doesn't works when I click on it, so I can't reply comments.

here my blog https://www.komputerkosan.com/2018/11/cara-mudah-membuat-stiker-whatsapp.html?showComment=1543499851561#r_c7252321218919566633

Comment: Your blog template contains encrypted javascript codes that obstruct some of template features. Use pastebin.com to add template code to your question.

Comment: can you give me detail information? because I don't understand what I should do with pastebin.com, I don't want to change my template

Comment: Just use it to upload your theme code and get URL in order to allow us to detect the issue.

Comment: I alreaady fixed it by myself, thanks for your help

Comment: @RennyXiao, how did you fix it? Please come back and post your own answer. Others may have your problem too.